# Jquery older version works but not newer

Tags: jquery

This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/U5BuM/  works in jquery 1.3.2 but not the latest 1.5.1. It was created using an old tutorial. Do you know how to make it work for 1.5.1?

Should I expect a lot of problems like this while learning jquery?  What's the best way to deal/ learn about these conflicts as I'm trying to learn jquery?

Comment: Although links to live examples are always a useful *adjunct*, **always** include the actual code in the question. People shouldn't have to follow the link to see what you're asking, and StackOverflow should stand alone. External links can get moved, deleted, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [putting quotes around the href selector](http://jsfiddle.net/U5BuM/3/):

```
$("li a[href$='.pdf']")...
```

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

> **attribute** An attribute name.
>
> **value** An attribute value. Quotes are mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find this works

```
$(function() {
  $("li a[href$='.pdf']")
  .after("<img src='http://quoraquora.com/small_pdf_icon.gif' align='absbottom' />");
});
```